# Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network in Oracle SQL Developer Tool

Tags: sybase

I am getting error while connecting to my database in Oracle SQL developer tool

```
"Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network"
```

Can any paramater be set in the tool to fix it out or any other suggestions ?

Comment: This will depend upon the tool connects to Sybase. I suspect this will be in JDBC or similar in which case you need to look up for that specific driver for the connection string to enable password encryption. This will then resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this link which all the possible parameters:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/prjdbc14.htm

Most likely you need 
ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true

Answer (score 0):

net password encryption reqd
the default value is 0
if set to 2
then maybe the error reported in your case

Answer (score 0):

we should pass the ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true:
example python:

```
import glob
driver_name='com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver'
driverpath=r"C:\Users\RameshPonnusamy\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\drivers\drivers\sybase\jconnect\jconn4.jar"        
import jaydebeapi
jclassname=driver_name
url="jdbc:sybase:Tds:{h}:{pr}".format(h=host,pr=port,db=database)
driver_args={'user': username, 'password':password,
                 'database': database,
                 'ENCRYPT_PASSWORD':'true'}
jars=glob.glob(driverpath)
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jclassname=jclassname,url=url, driver_args=driver_args, jars=jars)
```

If you are using IDE(Ex:Dbeaver)
Update  ***ENCRYPT_PASSWORD*** parameter as ***true***

```
right click on connection
 -->edit_connection(if it is already saved)
    -->Driver Properties-->click on value column cell of ENCRYPT_PASSWORD 
    ***type true*** and click ok
```

[image]