# Connection string for password encrypted Sybase in C#

Tags: c#, odbc, sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

I have this connection string, `DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=server_name;database=db_name;port=port_no;uid=user_id;pwd=password;` using which I could connect to Sybase database in C# using System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection class.

But now the database has been encrypted and gives this error `Adaptive Server requires encryption of the login password on the network.Login failed` .
Is there a way in which I can resolve the issue without downloading any libraries for different driver or data provider.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true` inside of your connection string.

It should end up looking like this: `DRIVER={Adaptive Server Enterprise};server=server_name;database=db_name;port=port_no;uid=user_id;pwd=password;ENCRYPT_PASSWORD=true;`

For more detailed answear, please refer to [this python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67439300/16638833)